# Dynamically create proc directory entries?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, procfs

I'm looking for a way to dynamically generate the contents of a directory in the /proc filesystem from a kernel module. This is definitely possible since the root /proc directory does it for each running process (and, indeed, that's actually what I want: to have one directory per PID inside of my /proc subdirectory – I'm trying to create a structure like `/proc/mymodule/<tgid>/<pid>`). However, the code that does this for the root `/proc` directory (found in `fs/proc/base.c`) is fairly complicated, and involves keeping an inode cache etc. Furthermore, none of the helper functions used in `fs/proc/base.c` are exported, so I'd have to copy & paste them into my module.

Is there any supported interface for dynamically generating the contents of a `/proc` directory whenever `readdir` is called?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `linux/proc_fs.h` it basically allows you to use `/proc` as a file system.

Take a look at [The Linux Kernel Module Programming Guide Ch. 5](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.6/html/c708.html) for reference.